# Online Music Degrees -- Free or not: Are they worth it?

Tags: lessons

Lately I have come across many online music degrees, certificates, and even online BA and MA programmes! I will list some examples below:

- Berklee's Introduction to Music Theory (Certificate).
  https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-music-theory-berkleex-oharm100x-3
- The University of Edinburgh's Fundamentals of Music Theory
  (Certificate). https://www.coursera.org/learn/edinburgh-music-theory
- Berklee's Music Composition for Film, TV, and Games (Bachelor's
  degree).
  https://online.berklee.edu/music-degrees/music-composition-for-film-tv-and-games

The tuition fees for the full online BA/MA programmes are simply out of my budget. They are simply five times more expensive than pursuing an on-campus Music BA in my city.

What is the value of Coursera/edX certificates? i.e. Let's say someone receives many of those online 'certificates' and has a very good understanding of music, theory, composition, etc. on the same level of an MA graduate, can he then enter a PhD in music?

Comment: I have removed the part of your question asking for free degrees. That is off topic here. The rest of your question is on topic.

Comment: This is an issue in many fields: if one has certain competences, but not documentation to "prove" it, then what? (Certificates will not successfully certify that one knows as much as a Bachelor's or Master's holder...)

Answer (score 6):

**The Berklee Introduction course** says "Length, 6 weeks, effort, 5 hours per week". Do you really think 30 hours study is enough to "enter a PhD in music?" There's nothing wrong with paying for a certificate if having the certificate makes you feel good, and the course is probably fine (Berklee certainly has a good reputation) - but this is a very basic introduction to the subject, not the equivalent of a BA in music.

Comparing it with UK music exams like ABRSM, it doesn't look equivalent even to ABRSM Grade 5 which is about the same academic level as the UK school GCSE exams intended for 16-year olds, and you would take two more years of school courses, after that, and pass another exam, to qualify to *start* a BA music degree at university.

**The Edinburgh course** looks to be at a similar level - the web site clearly says "Level: Beginner". For example the first 3 weeks of the 5 are about "how to read basic music notation" - so more than half the course is the musical equivalent of "learning to read English in elementary school".

**The Berklee "Music composition for Film, etc"** is at a higher level, but read the first sentence of the Overview: "Gain the practical skills to compose, arrange, and orchestrate effective dramatic music for visual media, including film, television, and interactive media." This is a *practical* course, not an *academic* one to prepare you for an MA or PhD. Also, note that the admission requirements include submitting two original compositions in sheet music form, plus a video demo of your performing ability.

If you read the all the comments, you find this difference between the Berklee college courses and the online version:

> While both degrees are from Berklee and share the same accreditation
>   from the New England Association of Schools and Colleges (NEASC), the
>   Bachelor’s of Music (BM) program has private lesson requirements,
>   ensemble/instrument lab requirements, audition requirements, and also
>   a different set of core music requirements. Otherwise, the BM and
>   Bachelor of Professional Studies (BPS) programs are the same. The
>   career opportunities for both programs are very similar. **However, if
>   you are planning to later pursue graduate and/or doctoral studies,
>   some of these programs require that students have a BM from undergrad.**

Comment: You must have completely misunderstood me. I did **NOT** say 'get one of those certificates and then apply for a PhD'. I said what if someone has **many** of those online certificates, in music theory, composition, etc. and has equally as much knowledge as a Master's degree student.

Comment: Ya know, the first part of this answer is pretty condescending

Comment: @aleph I have just removed that first sentence. As per Kolob's comment it just detracts from your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think these online courses just scratch the surface.  I have done alot my self but all it does is adding a little  to what you already know or just introducing  you to them as it were,  I think it makes more sense  to have one study properly in the institutions. In simple words I think the wax courses are certificate courses not degrees so can not be compare with BA or MA